# What are different among various dot nix files?

Tags: nix, nixos

I am new to `nixos`, this is my understanding about configurations

**Configuration files created by installer**

- `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` :: The central point of system description used by `nixos-rebuild`
- `/etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix` :: to be include in above `configuration.nix`

*Configuration files for packages*

- `<package>.nix` on nixpkgs [github](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs) :: configuration for each module (options are searchable on nixos package [page](http://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html))

**These are what I do not fully understand**

- `defatult.nix` (any where in filesystem) :: for `nix-shell` like `.bashrc`
- `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` :: `nix-env` overrided configuration for each users
- `~/.config/<various>.nix` :: ?? no idea

---

Am I understand it right?

Where can I find more information on these configuration files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call all of these files configuration files. E.g. the `<package>.nix` files are rather called derivations. What all these files share is the language in which they are written.

`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` is indeed where you configure your system and `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` where you configure `nix-env`.

`default.nix` doesn't mean anything in particular except that this is the default file that it selected by the commands `nix-build` and `nix-shell` when you give them a directory as argument instead of a specific file. Note e.g. that the nixpkgs collection (on GitHub like you noticed already) contains a lot of such `default.nix` files.

To understand all of this better I advise you to read [Nix-pills](http://lethalman.blogspot.fr/2014/07/nix-pill-1-why-you-should-give-it-try.html) (that's a long series but it's worth it) and of course the [NixOS](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/), [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/) and [nixpkgs](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/) manuals.